# Combining laser_scan_matcher with gmapping

Tags: ros, navigation, hokuyo-node, gmapping, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having hard time trying to set up a SLAM system with a laser scanner using **`gmapping`**. I installed **`laser_drivers`**, **`scan_tools`** and **`slam_gmapping`** stacks. I'm having no problems with [laser_scan_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_scan_matcher). I'm using the following launchfile for laser_scan_matcher and hokuyo_node:

**Deleted to avoid confusion, look at Ivan's answer below instead**

So so far I've got:

- a **`hokuyo_node`** publishing scans on a `/scan` topic
- a **`laser_scan_matcher`** publishing odometry tf on `/base_link` tf
- a tf tree set up as follows: `laser` -> `base_link` -> `world` (I don't actually know what the laser tf is here for, but it's been there in an example, so it stays for now)

What should my call to **`gmapping`** look like for the connection to **`laser_scan_matcher`** to work? Of course I tried a lot but none of the calls / launchfiles worked so I think it's best to ask an open question here first.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10909/combining-laser_scan_matcher-with-gmapping/) by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1079 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

gmapping needs odometry as /odom -> /base_link.
Setting the ~fixed_frame parameter from world to odom in the laser_scan_matcher should provide that. In this way the laser_scan_matcher should provide fake odometry by scanmatching.
Alternately you can set the ~odom_frame parameter in gmapping to world (only do one of these).

If you run gmapping now it should work.

The base_link -> laser transform gives the position of the laser relative to your robot. As you are passing 0 0 0, your are saying its in the center of the robot. You should adjust that to the real position of the laser.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-08-16**:
Right, edited my question to avoid confusion. Thank you.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-16**:
To set the odom_frame in gmapping, the cmd line should be _odom_frame:=world (note the leading _) as it sets a private parameter (noted ~... in the docs). You can leave the scan:=scan remapping as it changes nothing.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-08-16**:
I think a tutorial about using gmapping with laser_scan_matcher would be a big help to many here, so if anyone could come up with one, it would be great.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-08-16**:
Setting ~fixed_frame to odom and running gmapping with: rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan helped, thanks. I also tried running: rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan odom_frame:=world, but this didn't work because of missing transforms between world, base_link, laser and map.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Tom,

Sorry for not replying earlier - it looks like you might have it figured out already. I agree a tutorial would be very useful, and I'll work on putting one up.

In the meantime, here is a launch file to get you started. It uses the same recorded bag file that is in the `laser_scan_matcher/demo` directory. I will include it in the next release of `laser_scan_matcher`.

The only key thing that needs to be changed to pass the correct `fixed_frame` parameter to `laser_scan_matcher`.

```
<param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
```

This lets `laser_scan_matcher` publish it's f between `odom` and `base_link` (instead of `world` and `base_link`). Everything else should work out of the box.

```
<launch>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
   args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" />

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"/>

  <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag" 
    args="play $(find laser_scan_matcher)/demo/demo.bag --delay=5 --clock"/>
  
  <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" 
    name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="map_udpate_interval" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="delta" value="0.02"/>
  </node>

</launch>
```

**EDIT:**

I noticed the launch file you posted is very similar, but you told `gmapping` to use the `world` frame as it's odometry frame. While this will work, it is cleaner to go about it the way I suggested. The way you have it, the tf chain is:

`odom` --> `world` --> `base_link`

The correct chain, as suggested by the [ROS REP on coordinate frames](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html), should be:

`world` --> `odom` --> `base_link`

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-08-17**:
Thanks Ivan. A tutorial will be great as is laser_scan_matcher itself.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-08-17**:
@dornhege Yes I think you're right - my bad.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-08-17**:
Yes, that seems like a cleaner solution. I think @tom's has map->world->base_link and with your's will get map->odom->base_link.

**Comment by [tsdk00](https://answers.ros.org/users/37919/tsdk00/) on 2019-07-28**:
@tom Is there document / tutorial available for combing laser_scan_matcher and gmapping?